# Inconsistent translation in Azure DevOps UI

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm working with a distributed development team, managing projects through Azure DevOps. The parent company is in Germany and has all the servers based there.

When I use Azure DevOps, I changed my UI locale to English-US, but I'm still getting inconsistent translation of many UI items:

[image: Inconsistent translation]

This is a big impediment to our team because we don't understand German, so it's very hard to use Azure DevOps to collaborate.

Is there a way I can override these? Are these settings controlled by the Azure server (which we don't have access to)? I submitted a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/716831/azure-devops-language-overide-for-projects.html) to the Azure DevOps team, but I'd figure I'd ask here if anyone else ran into a similar situation or found a solution.

Edit: The company is using TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the response I received from Microsoft about this issue:

> Unfortunately, that's how TFS/Azure DevOps Server works.
>
> - The names of the work item types, as well as the field and state names, come from the process template.
> - Process templates only have a single language. It's the language in which TFS was installed.
> - So if you have a German TFS, it would give you a "Fehler" work item, instead of a "Bug" work item.
> - Other strings in the UI are available in multiple languages. When you change the preferred language for a user, you are changing it for the UI, but not for the process template (as it only has the one language).
>
> There's no built-in way to change the language of a process template, but it's possible to rename all strings back. It's also a requirement if you ever want to move your TFS in the cloud service.

Comment: It is a pity, Anyway this response can be regarded as an answer. You can accept it.